# How do I get a specific outfit at the start of GTA Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I notice that changing your lifestyle also changes your features / clothing. I was playing around with what hours I spent on everything after finding a good outfit, but even though I set the hours back at the same amount (or close to), the outfit is something else. Is there a guide to what numbers will give what outfit? or a way to manually change outfit?

Comment: If you're wondering about hats and sunglasses: they are chosen at random whenever your outfit changes and you can choose them after defining your lifestyle.

Comment: For me, it looked like that your outfit changes based on what stats you place. I kept adding a few points and removing a few points from one of the options and noticed that it chose one of several different outfits but eventually came back to the one I wanted. I think it's based from all of your stats though.
-kuma

Comment: @kuma I think it's actually based on whatever one's the highest - it switched whenever a different one became the highest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having had another play around with the character creator it seems that although the outfit is based on the various stats you've chosen, it also picks - at random - between 4 or 5 outfits.

You can test this yourself:

1. Set all your stats how you'd like them - your character will change into an outfit.
2. Pick a stat (let's go with Legal Work) and remove all the hours you put in. Hopefully, if you had enough in the first place you'll see your outfit change to something else.
3. Put the same amount of hours back into Legal Work.
4. Chances are you'll have a different outfit to the one before.
5. Using this process I was able to cycle through the outfits available to my character and pick one I preferred.

I can't find any definitive list of outfits but this should help finding the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely start with a suit, I had to show up when I put stats like going to legit work and sleeping but then I couldn't replicate it.